# Is the pattern I'm using for flash messages (with Turbo/Hotwire) in Rails 7 during a failed create action clean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 7.1.2

I have a form to create a new `Employer` that exists on the `Employers#index` view

```html
# app/views/employers/index.html.erb

<div class="p-3">
  <h1 class="text-2xl">Add an Employer</h1>
  <%= form_with scope: @employer, url: employers_path, method: :post, data: { controller: "reset-form", action: "turbo:submit-end->reset-form#reset" },class: "flex justify-center" do |form| %>
    <table class="table" id="add_employer">
      <tr>
        <td><%= form.label :name %></td>
        <td><%= form.text_field :name %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><%= form.label :city %></td>
        <td><%= form.text_field :city %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><%= form.label :state %></td>
        <td><%= form.text_field :state %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><%= form.label :website %></td>
        <td><%= form.text_field :website %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><%= form.label :industry %></td>
        <td><%= form.text_field :industry %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><%= form.label :employees %></td>
        <td><%= form.text_field :employees %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="text-center" id="submit-button-tr">
        <td></td>
        <td class="p-3"><%= form.submit "Add company", class: "btn btn-blue" %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The form will send a POST request to `Employers#create` action in the `Employers_controller`:

```rb
# app/controllers/employers_controller.rb

  def create
    @employer = Employer.new(employer_params)

    @pagy, @employers = pagy(Employer.sort_by_name)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @employer.save
        format.turbo_stream { flash.now[:success] = "The employer #{@employer.name} was successfully added." }
      else
        format.turbo_stream { flash.now[:alert] = "Please try again" }
      end
    end
  end
```

The `Employer` validates for all fields before persisting to the database:

```rb
# app/models/employer.rb

class Employer < ApplicationRecord
  scope :sort_by_name, -> { distinct(:name).order(:name) }

  validates :name, :city, :state, :website, :industry, :employees, presence: true
end
```

The `Employers#index` view is being updated via Turbo Streams upon successful/unsuccessful creation:

```
# create.turbo_stream.erb

<%= turbo_stream.update "employers" do %>
  <table class="table-fixed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Employer Name</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th><%= link_to "State", sort: "state" %></th>
        <th>Industry</th>
        <th># of Employees</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @employers.each do |employer| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= link_to "#{employer.name}", employer.website %></td>
          <td><%= employer.city %></td>
          <td><%= employer.state %></td>
          <td><%= employer.industry %></td>
          <td><%= employer.employees %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<% end %>

<%= turbo_stream.update "flash" do %>
  <%= render  partial: "layouts/flash" %>
<% end %>
```

I had to use turbo frames/turbo streams and a `_flash` partial to get the flash message to render, since I want `Employers#index` to update automatically upon successful/unsuccessful persistence to the database.

My primary question is: Is there a better way to render the flash messages that *doesn't* use turbo streams?